# Cliente TCP android não funciona

Tags: java, c#, android-studio

Boa Tarde,

Eu estou criando uma aplicação no android studio para enviar uma string do smartphone para o pc.

A minha aplicação tem o seguinte código:

```
public void Send_Command(View v) {

  testClass();

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Comando Enviado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public static void testClass() {
  Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
  cThread.start();
}

public static class ClientThread implements Runnable {

  String results = "";

  public void run() {
    try {
      InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
      System.out.println("C: Connecting...");
      while (true) {
        results = "";
        try {
          Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.77", 8888);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
          out.write("Test");
          out.flush();
          String inMsg = "";
          boolean b = false;
          while (!b) {
            inMsg = in .readLine();
            if (inMsg != "")
              b = true;
          }
          socket.close();
          System.out.println("C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("S: Error" + e.toString());
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("C: Error" + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Eu coloquei o Send_Message no onClick de um botão e quando eu executo o aplicativo com um servidor em C# aberto no pc nada acontece, porém se eu executar o mesmo código do android studio no eclipse, com o mesmo servidor em C# aberto, a conexão é estabelecida e a string enviada.

Eu sou novo em programação para android, então é possível que esteja a cometer algum erro básico, no entanto não sei onde.

Alguém sabe onde pode estar o erro ?

Obrigado

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "quando eu executo o aplicativo com um servidor em C# aberto no pc nada acontece"? Você está executando o aplicativo no celular e apontando para o PC que está como servidor? Verificou as regras de firwall e se o device está na mesma rede do PC?

Comment: Sim, os dispositivos estão na mesma rede, e o endereço ip do PC com o servidor é o mesmo que eu indico na App. A firewall do PC que tem o servidor está desativada.